# To count or not to count, that is the question

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
Strawberries 2
Strawberries 3
Strawberries 4
Chocolate 3
Chocolate 4
Chocolate 5
Chocolate 6
Apples 3
Apples 4
Apples 5
Apples 6
```

My idea is to get the number of items, and the total of items per thing, like so:

```
Item         Number        Total
Strawberries 2             9
Strawberries 3             9
Strawberries 4             9
Chocolate    3             18
Chocolate    4             18
Chocolate    5             18
Chocolate    6             18
Apples       3             18
Apples       4             18
Apples       5             18
Apples       6             18
```

So i'm doing:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT item, number, COUNT(number) AS total FROM products
GROUP BY item, number
ORDER BY item
```

But the numbers i get are all wrong:

```
Item         Number        Total
Strawberries 2             6
Strawberries 3             21
Strawberries 4             17
Chocolate    3             1
Chocolate    4             8
Chocolate    5             34
Chocolate    6             1
Apples       3             1
Apples       4             10
Apples       5             32
Apples       6             1
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  item, number, SUM(number) OVER (PARTITION BY item)
FROM    products
ORDER BY
        item, number
```

Comment: I think you mean to `SUM(number)` not `COUNT(*)`.